# Monotonic Functions

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, monotone-functions

> $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ monotonic function with $f(1/4)f(3/4)<0$. Suppose 
>   $\sup\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)<0\}=\alpha$. Which of the following statements are true?
>
> $1$ $f(\alpha)<0$
>
> $2$ if $f$ is increasing then $f(\alpha)\leq0$
>
> $3$ if $f$ is continuous and $1/4<\alpha<3/4$ then $f(\alpha)=0$
>
> $4$ if $f$ is decreasing then $f(\alpha)<0$

My Try:

Since $\alpha$ is supremum of this set $f(\alpha)\geq0$. First option not true in general. By intermediate value theorem third option is true.

Since $\alpha$ is supremum and $f$ is increasing, $\alpha-\varepsilon<x\implies f(\alpha-\varepsilon)\leq f(x)<0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ hence $f(\alpha)\geq0$

Since $\alpha$ is supremum and $f$ is decreasing, $\alpha-\varepsilon<x\implies 0>f(\alpha-\varepsilon)\geq f(x)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ hence $f(\alpha)<0$

Second option is false and fourth is true.

Are my arguments correct? I have some doubts over my arguments for second and fourth options . Could anybody clarify?

Comment: I think your conclusions are correct, though I think you might be able to  improve your arguments. I would produce a specific counter-example for the second while on the fourth I would say $f(3/4) <0$ so $f(1) \lt 0$ and so $\alpha=1$ and $f(\alpha) < 0$.

Comment: Thank you Henry. guess $f(x)=\begin{cases}[4(x-1/2)] &x\in[0,1/2)\cup[3/4,1]\\ [4(x-1/2)]+1 &x\in[1/2,3/4)\end{cases}$ should work as counter example.

Comment: How is f an increasing function? f(5/8)=3/2 but f(3/4)=1.

Comment: $f(x)=\begin{cases}x-1 &x\in[0,1/2)\\ x &x\in[1/2,1]\end{cases}$ might be a simpler counter-example for the second